# Mini display port cable and Thunderbolt cable compatibility

Tags: imac, thunderbolt, displayport, compatibility, xserve

I need to run a Mini DisplayPort cable from a [last generation Xserve](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/xserve/stats/xserve-intel-nehalem-xeon-2.26-2009-quad-specs.html) to a circa [late 2010 iMac](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/imac/stats/imac-core-i3-3.06-21-inch-aluminum-mid-2010-specs.html) so I can directly share the iMac's display while I set up the Xserve.

Apple no longer carries Mini DisplayPort cables at their stores here in NY.  No one at the store could tell me if I could use a Thunderbolt cable with the hardware I have.

So, a hopefully simple backwards compatibility question: Can I use a Thunderbolt cable to connect the Mini DisplayPort of the Xserve to the Mini DisplayPort of the iMac?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [this source](http://mike952.wordpress.com/2011/07/21/thunderbold-and-minidisplay-mac-compatibility-101/), you will not be able to use a Thunderbolt cable in this fashion.

You can, however, get a Mini DisplayPort to Mini DisplayPort cable from [Monoprice for about $5](http://www.monoprice.com/products/product.asp?c_id=102&cp_id=10246&cs_id=1024602&p_id=5991&seq=1&format=2) and that should work just fine.

Comment: @Mat_Love I hoped for something I could get in NY today, but you've given me the right answer.  Thanks.